# Kivy on Android Buttons have weird symbols instead of text

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Stack Overflow
I am a newbie in Kivy, buildozer and app development in general and trying to figure out a certain problem:

1. I deployed my Calculator app to my android device.
2. When I opened it, I saw that the text of the `Button` widgets have weird white square symbols instead of text.
3. I have to mention that the text is supposed to be black and when I press it, the symbol disappears and the `Button` becomes empty.
4. I tried building without my custom font, nothing changed. The program works well on pc.

Here is a screenshot from my app: [calculator app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lkx.jpg)

There is my main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
import math

Config.set('kivy', 'window_icon', "calculator.ico")

class CalculatorLayout(Widget):
    operators = {'+', '-', '*', '/'}
    forbidden = {'+', '/', '*', '.'}
    all = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '.'}
    md = {'*', '/'}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.exp = '0'

    def add(self, arg):
        split = self.split()
        if self.exp == '0' and not(arg in self.forbidden):
            self.exp = arg
        else:
            if (arg == '.') and (split[-1].count('.') == 1 or split[-1] in self.operators):
                pass
            elif (arg in self.operators) and (self.exp[-1] in self.all):
                pass
            else:
                self.exp += arg
        self.update()

    def submit(self):
        if self.exp[-1] in self.all:
            self.exp = self.exp[:-1]
        self.exp = str(eval(self.exp))
        self.update()

    def pow(self):
        if self.exp[-1] in self.all:
            self.exp = self.exp[:-1]
        self.exp = str(eval(self.exp)**2)
        self.update()

    def sqrt(self):
        if self.exp[-1] in self.all:
            self.exp = self.exp[:-1]
        self.exp = str(math.sqrt(eval(self.exp)))
        self.update()

    def delete(self):
        self.exp = self.exp[:-1]
        if not self.exp:
            self.exp = '0'
        self.update()

    def clear(self):
        self.exp = '0'
        self.update()

    def split(self):
        self.expSplit = []
        self.elem = ''
        for i, char in enumerate(self.exp):
            if char in self.operators:
                if self.elem:
                    self.expSplit.append(self.elem)
                self.elem = ''
                self.expSplit.append(char)
            else:
                self.elem += char
        if self.elem:
            self.expSplit.append(self.elem)
            self.elem = ''
        print(self.expSplit)
        return self.expSplit

    def update(self):
        self.box_design.text = self.exp


class CalculatorApp(App):
    Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    def build(self):
        self.icon = "calculator.png"
        Window.clearcolor = (232/255, 232/255, 232/255, 1)
        return CalculatorLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

This is my main.kv:

```
#:import rgb functions.rgb
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<Button>
    size_hint: 0.33333333, 0.2
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: rgb(201, 201, 201, 1)
    color: "black"
    font_name: "digital-7.ttf"
    font_size: 24
    background_down: ""
    on_press:
        self.background_color = rgb(158, 158, 158, 1)
    on_release:
        self.background_color = rgb(201, 201, 201, 1)

<CalculatorLayout>
    box_design: box
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size: root.width, root.height
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Label:
                id: box
                padding: (5, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                valign: "middle"
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 48
                font_name: 'digital-7.ttf'
                text: "0"
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 1)
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            spacing: 1
            StackLayout:
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                spacing: 1
                Button:
                    text: 'Clear'
                    font_size: 24 if Window.size[0] >= 400 else 20
                    font_size: 16 if Window.size[0] <= 300 else 24
                    on_press: root.clear()
                Button:
                    text: 'x^2'
                    font_size: 24 if Window.size[0] >= 400 else 20
                    font_size: 16 if Window.size[0] <= 300 else 24
                    on_press: root.pow()
                Button:
                    text: "sqrt(x)"
                    font_size: 24 if Window.size[0] >= 400 else 20
                    font_size: 16 if Window.size[0] <= 300 else 24
                    on_press: root.sqrt()
                Button:
                    text: '7'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '8'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '9'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '4'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '5'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '6'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '1'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '2'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '3'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '0'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '.'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    text: '='
                    on_press: root.submit()
            StackLayout:
                spacing: 1
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: "Delete" if Window.size[0] >= 350 else "Del"
                    font_size: 24 if Window.size[0] >= 400 else 20
                    font_size: 16 if Window.size[0] <= 300 else 24
                    on_press: root.delete()
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: '/'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: '*'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: '-'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: '+'
                    on_press: root.add(self.text)
```

Comment: Looks a lot like a font problem. What happens if you include a standard kivy Label with some text, is that text also bad?

Comment: Same problem, I did specify that building without custom font doesn't resolve the problem. Also it is only an Android problem, because my program runs smoothly on PC.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. After some detailed manipulations with my code, I found out that the problem was with the `Button` color. Looks like android can't load `"black"` string color value. I changed it to a rgb value `(0, 0, 0, 1)` and it's working.